# Divide page in two columns and align them in HTML

Tags: html, css, salesforce, responsive, lightning

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSsUi.png)I would like to display the page in two columns below the heading and center align the buttons the way it is.

I do not understand if I have missed any divs here?

I have been trying to do it but its not showing up the way i expected.

```
<div>
        <div class="slds-p-top--x-large slds-text-align--center slds-p-bottom_small" width="100%">
        <span>Help us improve Customer Support</span>
        </div>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%" class="divText slds-p-bottom--medium leftBtn" >Tell us what you think<br/>
        <div  class="slds-text-align--center slds-p-top--small slds-p-bottom--large slds-p-top--medium">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">
        <span class="btn-feedback">Provide feedback</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td width="50%" class="vertical-liness divText slds-p-bottom--medium rightBtn" >Collaborate with our team<br/>
        <div  class="slds-text-align--center slds-p-top--small slds-p-bottom--large slds-p-top--medium">
         <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">
         <span class="btn-feedback">Get Involved</span>
         </button>
         </div>
         </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

        .THIS .vertical-liness 
        { 
            border-left: 2px solid red;            
        }

        .THIS .leftBtn{
            padding-left:115px; 
            float:right;
        }

    .THIS .rightBtn{
        padding-left:175px;
    }

    .THIS {
        background-color: #f4f7f7;  /* ibm-cool-white-3; */
        border-top: 1px solid #d0dada; /* ibm-gray-10 */
        font-size: 20px; 
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #272727;  /* ibm-gray-90 */
    }

    .THIS .divText{
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #272727;  /* ibm-gray-90 */
    }
```

Comment: post the complete html and css for the problem you're trying to solve. see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: There is **no** CSS method of aligning elements that do not share a parent.

Comment: @Michael Coker, i added the complete html and image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your markup to show an example. You can create a couple of flex parents and use their centering properties to recreate this.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.col {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.button {
  padding: 0 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
.button1 {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
header {
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex col">
  <header>
    Help us improve Customer Support
  </header>
  <div class="buttons flex">
    <div class="button button1">
      <div>
        Tell us what you think
      </div>
      <button>Provide feedback</button>
    </div>
    <div class="button button2">
      <div>
        Tell us what you think
      </div>
      <button>Provide feedback</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked as expected, now I see what I did, I haven't wrapped the headings properly. Thanks much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two divs in your body and place the content inside each of them.

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.left, .right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
    <p>Left column</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <p>Right column</p>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgLKzQ

Comment: Thanks I was having issues wrapping up the button. I was able to divide the page in two columns.

Answer (score 0):

`float: left;` with `width: 50%;` is the key here.

Be careful that you need either *content* inside your div like the below example, either give them an *height* (eg. CSS: `.left-float { height: 500px; }`

Be careful either that floating elements will break the flow. 
You will need to clear float with the next elements: 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clear/

CSS :

```
.left-float {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div>
    <div class="left-float" style="background-color:green;">
    left div
    </div>
    <div class="left-float" style="background-color:red;">
    right div
    </div>
</div>
```

So, with your code... Ugh, put me off this `<table>` element please ! 
They are designed to display tabular data and not to provide a way of positioning elements. In your case you do not display tabular data.

An example of how it could be : 
https://jsfiddle.net/12fd30bf/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="slds-p-top--x-large slds-text-align--center slds-p-bottom_small" width="100%">
      <span>Help us improve Customer Support</span>
    </div>
    <div class="left-float"> 
        Tell us what you think<br/>
        <div  class="slds-text-align--center slds-p-top--small slds-p-bottom--large slds-p-top--medium">
          <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">
            <span class="btn-feedback">Provide feedback</span>
          </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-float">
        Collaborate with our team<br/>
        <div  class="slds-text-align--center slds-p-top--small slds-p-bottom--large slds-p-top--medium">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">
              <span class="btn-feedback">Get Involved</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.left-float {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was having issues wrapping up the button. I was able to divide the page in two columns.